# Intellije not adding dependencies to class path

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

For some reason in Intellije Community Edition 14, the maven dependencies are not being found.

[image: dependencies not found]

[image: maven is not downloading files]

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing, I have tried re-importing the maven pom.xml, I have tried deleting all .idea and .iml files, I have tried Re-importing the project through intellije, I have tried deleting the entire project directory and re-downloading from git, and finally I have even tried running the code through maven - nothing is fixing my IDE! Please help!

Comment: "mvn clean compile" from command line works (and through maven project cycle in intellije), but intellije compiler is not finding anything

Comment: Also, when I look at the External Libraries tab, I can see there is nothing there

Comment: Note, this was working at one point, but then just stopped working all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured out an even better solution.

My project actually has a fairly complex POM which has parents of other POMs and a complex structure that Intellij didn't like for reasons unknown (Maven compiles worked on command line but Intellij couldn't resolve the POM).

Because of this, no updates would happen, even after updating the workspace.

However, if you simply comment out the lines Intellij doesn't understand, you dependencies will be downloaded correctly. In my case, I just commented out my parent POM and all was well!

You should ultimately try to figure out what is causing said issue, but this will allow you to continue working.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new workspace so no configs previously messed up were used. Problem solved!